# Проблема с сеттером

Tags: kotlin, классы, setter

```
open class NumInc(var number: Int, step: Int) {
    constructor(): this(0, 1)
    var step = step
        set(value) {
            field = if (value != 0)
                value
            else
                1
        }
    open fun inc() { number += step }
    open fun dec() { number -= step }
}
class NumDouble(number: Int, step: Int): NumInc(number, step) {
    override fun inc() { number += step * 2}
    override fun dec() { number -= step * 2}
}
fun main() {
    val a = NumDouble(3, 0)
    val b = NumInc(3, 0)
    a.inc()
    b.inc()
    println(a.number)
    println(b.number)
}
```

По идее, в b step должен поменяться с 0 на 1, и вывод должен быть "3 4", а вывод - "3 3".

Comment: А где тут по вашему сеттер используется? Конструктор его не вызывает.

Comment: Конструктор же не должен использоваться, передаются конкретные значения.

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/constructors

Answer (score 0):

1. У параметра `step` в конструкторе класса `NumInc` нет ни `var:`, ни `val:`

   ```
   open class NumInc(var number: Int, step: Int) {
   ```

   потому Kotlin *не изменит его автоматически в свойство (property).*

   Он остается *только параметром,* и как такой будет *неизменяемым (immutable).*
2. Командой

   ```
    var step = step
   ```

   вы определяете *свойство* этого класса, т.е. **что-то другое**, доступное и изменяемым из вне в виде `объект.step`. (Тем самым вы перекрываете имя `step` как имя параметра).
3. Затем вы командой

   ```
        set(value) {
   ```

   определяете сеттер для этого свойства, **но его код не исполняется немедленно**, как вы, вероятно, думали; **он «спит», ожидая  на присвоения в виде**

   ```
   объект.step = что-то
   ```

   когда он реально запускается и выполняется.

---

*Решение:*

Достаточно только добавить команду

```
b.step = 0
```

после создания объекта `b` в функции `main()`, чтобы ваш код делал то, чего вы хотели:

```
fun main() {
    val a = NumDouble(3, 0)
    val b = NumInc(3, 0)
    b.step = 0                # только здесь запускается ваш сеттер
    a.inc()
    b.inc()
    println(a.number)
    println(b.number)
}
```

---

*Вывод:*

> ```
> 3
> 4
> ```

Comment: Нет никакого "спящего" кода, у свойства есть `initializer, getter, and setter`, соответсвенно конструктор всегда вызывает первый, который модифицирует `backing field` напрямую. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#getters-and-setters

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, вы серьезно думаете, что ваш специальный комментарий поможет начинающему программисту лучше понять, в чем он ошибся? Или, наоборот, он может у него вызвать сомнение, если мой ответ правильный?

Comment: Я надеюсь что он вызовет у него хоть какое-то желание читать документацию и вникать в суть вещей вместо копи-паста чужого кода.